# Is there any benefit to using one jsonb column on a table rather than bunch of them for better organization?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Is there any benefit to using one big `jsonb` column type in a `Postgresql` table like `data` with top level keys of `address` and `fee` verses a lot of them like `address_data` and `fee_data`?

Comment: Consider making them normal columns.

Comment: The best thing is to avoid JSON in the database completely unless you know what you are doing, and it cannot be represented well with a normal relational model.